# Concatenate variable and lookup expression

Tags: xpath, xslt-3.0

Using `json-doc()` I store JSON in a variable `$db.data.work`.
Then I process XML where I have placeholders like this

```xml
<persName>{API:?*[?role_en='Composer']?person?firstName} {API:?*[?role_en='Composer']?person?lastName})</persName>
```

The idea is to use the part after "API:" in order to retrieve the values from `$db.data.work` and replace the placeholders. How could I concatenate the variable and the lookup expressions in order them to be evaluated?

```xml
<template name="replace.api.placeholders">

    <variable name="pattern.api.placeholders" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">\{API:(.+?)\}</variable>
    <analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern.api.placeholders}">
      <matching-substring>
        <value-of select="
            let $db.key := regex-group(1)
            return
              if ($db.data.work<appended-retrieved-expression>) then
                $db.data.work<appended-retrieved-expression
                else
                  ."/>
      </matching-substring>
      <non-matching-substring>
        <value-of select="."/>
      </non-matching-substring>
    </analyze-string>
  </template>
```

I naively tried to concatenate both as strings and then evaluate using the curly braces or without.

```xml
    <value-of select="
                let $statement :=     '$db.data.work' || '?persons?*[?role_en=\"Composer\"]?person?firstName' 
                return
                  if ({$statement}) then
                            {$statement}
                  else              
                      ."/>
```

Note that just injecting one key works fine:

```xml
    <value-of select="
                let $db.key := regex-group(1)
                return
                  if ($db.data.work?($db.key)) then
                    $db.data.work?($db.key)
                  else              
                      ."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xsl:evaluate`:

```
<xsl:evaluate xpath="regex-group(1)" context-item="$db.data.work"/>
```

Needs Saxon 10 or higher for HE, for PE and EE 9.8 or higher.

Minimal example (your input):

```
<persName>{API:?*[?role_en='Composer']?person?firstName} {API:?*[?role_en='Composer']?person?lastName})</persName>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="persName">
    <xsl:variable name="pattern.api.placeholders" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">\{API:(.+?)\}</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern.api.placeholders}">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:evaluate xpath="regex-group(1)" context-item="$db.data.work"/>
      </xsl:matching-substring> 
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="db.data.work" select="parse-json($json-string)"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="json-string" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">[
    { "role_en" : "Composer", "person": { "firstName": "Johann Sebastian", "lastName":"Bach" } }
  ]</xsl:param>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm getting
"Dynamic error in expression {nma_title_de} called using xsl:evaluate: The required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(); the supplied value map{(:size 29:)} is a map"
as $db.data.work is a map.

Comment: Also tried 
`let $key := ('nma_title_de') return  $db.data.work?$key` and getting:
The XPath parer is not configured to allow use of XPath 4.o syntax.

I'm using oXygen 25.1.

Comment: I made an example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH7UCT. If you still have problems please edit your question and show a minimal but complete JSON sample you have in that variable `$db.data.work`.

Comment: Yes, it works fine!
The problem was that some values after API was not valid lookup expressions so a dynamic error was raised. I solved it with xsl:try/xsl:catch. Maybe there are better solutions to handle this?

Comment: If you can't fix the data then I think try/catch for the dynamic evaluation is fine.